# VirtualBox with aMule - How to configure network, port forwarding... properly?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, virtualbox, file-sharing

for security reasons I am running [aMule](http://www.amule.org/) inside VirtualBox.

- Guest and Host systems are Linux (to be more specific Arch 64 distro)
- Host system has public ip directly connected to internet (no router)
- Guest System I almost pure after installation (no iptables, etc only VirtualBox addons)
- I'd like to setup three ports for aMule: 4884, 4885, 4887
- I'd love to use [NAT VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) interface, if possible

For this case I've made following [forwarding rules](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html):

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "$vm" --natpf1 "amule_u4,udp,,4884,,4884"
VBoxManage modifyvm "$vm" --natpf1 "amule_u5,udp,,4885,,4885"
VBoxManage modifyvm "$vm" --natpf1 "amule_u7,udp,,4887,,4887"
VBoxManage modifyvm "$vm" --natpf1 "amule_t4,tcp,,4884,,4884"
VBoxManage modifyvm "$vm" --natpf1 "amule_t5,tcp,,4885,,4885"
VBoxManage modifyvm "$vm" --natpf1 "amule_t7,tcp,,4887,,4887"
```

On Host I've added to `/etc/hosts.allow` :

```
# amule
4884: ALL
4885: ALL
4887: ALL
```

Sanity check made with `netcat` works:

```
netcat -l -p 4885 # inside VM
netcat $ip 4885  # from "outside world"
```

To ensure:

```
aMule standard TCP Port: 4884
UDP port for server requests (TCP+3): 4887
Extended UDP port (Kad/global search): 4885
```

But aMule gets only **"Low-ID"** and **"Kad: Firewalled"**.

Is it possible to configure VM's Nat interface and aMule to cooperate nicely ? If yes, how ?

If it is not possible, why? And how to do this other way?

Comment: Cross linking: http://forum.amule.org/index.php?topic=19969.0